# C# changed specific value int and looping

Tags: c#, loops, integer

i changed the question sample, i hope everyone understand what i meant.
i'm use .NET WinformApp

i want to make label1.Text gonna be show 1->2->3 and back to 1 again like repeat or looping from 1,2,3

i try this sample :

```
public void test(int value)
{
  label1.Text = value.ToString();
}
public void Timer1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int checkvalue = 0;
   int A = 1; int B = 2; int C = 3;
   if (checkvalue == 0) { test(A); checkvalue = 1; }
   if (checkvalue == 1) { test(B); checkvalue = 2; }
   if (checkvalue == 2) { test(C); checkvalue = 0; }
}
```

but label1.Text just only show 3

Comment: It seems to work as you expect if you fix the problems with the code that prevent it compiling: https://rextester.com/JXMY70393 - this leads me to think I didn't understand your question.

Comment: i my visual studio app its dosent work why its works on rextester

Comment: i'm already edit this question did you understand what i meant?

Comment: You need to return from each if block or change the second and third ifs to else-ifs. Otherwise it will finish one block and then go straight to the next one without waiting.

Comment: could  you give me sample code?

Comment: You need sample code to know how to change an `if` into an `else if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, `checkvalue` and the values `A`, `B`, and `C` are local variables. That is to say: they are created when the `Timer1` method is called, and cease to exist when the `Timer1` method ends. The entire `Timer1` method will execute within less time than the blink of an eye, so all of your logic will execute almost at once. This means that by the end of `Timer1`, `test` has been called for `A`, `B`, and `C`, and `checkvalue` has cycled through 0, 1, 2, and back to 0.

What you need to do is define field variables within the class instead:

```cs
public class MyFormClass : Form // this already exists in your code, but the name might be different
{
    private int checkvalue = 0;
    // It's not clear what A, B, and C reprsent, but if they should be able to 
    // change between calls to Timer1, you may also want these to be field
    // variables or perhaps properties

    public void test(int value)
    {
      label1.Text = value.ToString();
    }
```

The next problem to address is your `if` statements. After the first one is evaluated and its body executed, the next one will also be executed because you've now set `checkvalue` to the correct value for the evaluation of the boolean expression to pass. We should therefore change it to an `if/else if/else` pattern so that only one call to `test` will occur per execution of `Timer1`:

```cs
public void Timer1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int A = 1; int B = 2; int C = 3;

   if (checkvalue == 0)
   {
       test(A);
       checkvalue = 1;
   }
   else if (checkvalue == 1)
   {
       test(B);
       checkvalue = 2;
   }
   else
   {
       test(C);
       checkvalue = 0;
   }
}
```

This should achieve your desired logic of looping across A, B, and C over and over.

Another way to do this might be to use an array and a track the position. That way you could add more items without adding more if/else if/else statements:

```cs
public class MyFormClass : Form
{
    private int position = 0;
    private int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

    public void test(int value)
    {
      label1.Text = value.ToString();
    }    

    public void Timer1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test(values[position]);
        // Increment position and reset to 0 if it goes beyond
        // the end of the array
        if (++position >= values.Length)
        {
            position = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have  another question how if i have A, B, C, D, E

its gonna be if, else if, else, else, else or if, else if, else if, else if, ,else

Comment: thanks i'm already try and its worked

Comment: @Okta In a simple way, yes. But I'd suggest using an array instead (see my revision).

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
if (checkvalue == 0){ test(A); checkvalue == 1;}
```

Look carefully at the final statement:

```
 checkvalue == 1;
```

Does it look like an assignment expression, or an equality comparison?

Comment: checkvalue == 1; i wrote this hope will do next if (checkvalue == 1) function

Comment: It's a comparison. It doesn't do anything. Make it an assignment, and you'll be closer to what you want.